# Visual Studio error D8016: '/ZI' and '/O2' command-line options are incompatible

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio error D8016: '/ZI' and '/O2' command-line options are incompatible

I'm using optimization for the first time with C++.
When I 'build solution' I keep getting this error. 
In the property pages, I have configuration set to Release
Under project/properties/c++/optimization I tried all the options except for disable.
Under project/properties/c++/General I also tried all the options under 'Debug Information Format' (assume 'None' is a good choice?).
I think it might have something to do with the linker settings, but still don't know what to do.

Comment: Well, that cannot work, Edit+Continue is not supported for optimized code.  You must use /Zi instead.  Do use the project templates available in VS, no point getting stuck on a silly problem like this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to the project's property page and change the value for:

```
C/C++ | General | Debug Information Format
```

To something other than "Program Database for Edit and Continue (/ZI)"

For example, "Program Database (/Zi)" should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that seems to have worked, but now I'm getting 'error D8016: '/O2' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible'. I have "Basic Runtime Checks" set to default. I tried the other settings and also entering "None". I'm working on a console app.

Comment: @NathanSchmidt: Again a case of mixing debug and release options. As Hans Passant pointed out, MSVC has good defaults for beginners.

Comment: Thanks ,, helped me too.

Answer (score 2):

After changing

```
C/C++ | General | Debug Information Format
```

to `Program Database (/Zi)`

You might need to set the `solution configurations` to `Release`.

Comment: Thanks. it helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that under Linker -> Debugging says Generate Debug Info -> No.

I had this problem as well.