# error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Ox' command-line options are incompatible VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am getting this error in VS2012. I tried the following [Visual Studio error D8016: '/ZI' and '/O2' command-line options are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336562/visual-studio-error-d8016-zi-and-o2-command-line-options-are-incompatible)

I don't know if this may be the problem, but in Property Manager I also have two Property Sheets that are greyed out called Application and Dynamic Link to MFC. I believe these may be causing the problem...is it possible to get rid of these?

EDIT: Missed to add a lot more information.

My current settings on Release are Debug Information Format - Zi(program database) and Optimization - None. When I change the "main" configuration settings to No Debug and Optimization to O2(Optimize Speed) or Ox ( Full Optimization ) it recognizes the change to Optimization, but does not recognize that I do not want debug information hence the error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`/ZI` is the Edit & Continue feature (aka increment linking). You cannot use any optimization with Edit & Continue (i.e. only `/Od` which is disable optimization).

Most projects are set up so that the Debug build has `/ZI` and `/Od`, while Release builds do not make use of `/ZI`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that when I try to disable Debug build and enable Optimization, for some reason /ZI is still being enabled.

Comment: That's in the Release version